# Can I create an object with fields in Javascript and have VS2012 show these in intellisense?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I am declaring the following within my script

```
function dialog($link) {
    var modal = {};
    ...

    function createModal() {
        modal.$modal = $.modal({
            title: title,
            closeButton: true,
            content: content,
            onClose: onModalClose,
            minWidth: 300,
            maxHeight: false,
            width: false,
            resizeOnLoad: true
        });
        modal.$form = $modal.find('.form');
        modal.$message = $modal.find('.message');
        modal.$submits = $modal.find('.submit-button');
        modal.href = $form.attr('data-href');
    }
```

There's no error checking here so if I wanted I could then go on and 
write the following:

```
var a = modal.$formmmmmmmm;
```

I am used to C# where I declare a class and everything is defined. Is there some
way that I could do this in Javascript? I heard VS2012 is a lot better with 
javascript. Is anyone using this and will it give me intellisense using my code
above or will I need to do things differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll at least need to initialize the properties on the object, and in order to get more information with intellisense you'll need to create appropriate XML comments:

```
/// <var>object description</var>
var modal = {
    /// <field type='jQuery'>$modal description</field>
    $modal: null,
    /// <field type='jQuery'>$form description</field>
    $form: null,
    /// <field type='jQuery'>$message description</field>
    $message: null,
    /// <field type='jQuery'>$submits description</field>
    $submits: null,
    /// <field type='String'>href description</field>
    href: null
};
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx for further explanation and examples.

And if you are feeling adventurous, have a look at [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), it makes JavaScript development *finally* comfortable.